# Images are blurry on some devices

Tags: wordpress, image, filter

My problem is basically, the images on this page- https://sawa-architecture.org/projects/ - are loading blurry and I cannot find a solution. Although initially blurry (only on older macs and pcs it seems,  when I apply the filter on the projects the images are sharp again.

I've tried compressing the images with wp-optimise. Also, tried using smaller images, but doesn't explain why it loads fine when I run the filter. So I'm pretty sure it must be something to do with my filter code.

All
                            
                                    name) ?>" checked/>name ?>
                                    

                            Apply

```
    <div id="response">

             <?php wp_reset_postdata(); if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <div class="container">

                                    <div class="container-grid projects-grid">

                                            <?php
                                            /* Start the Loop */
                                            while ( have_posts() ) :
                                                the_post();?>

                                                        <div class="grid-item">
                                                                <a href="<?= the_permalink() ?>">
                                                                    <?php
                                                                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                                                            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                                                                    }?>
                                                                    <h3><?= the_title() ?></h3>
                                                                </a>
                                                        </div>

                                            <?php endwhile;?>

                         </div><!--end container-grid-->

                     </div><!--end container-fluid-->
            <?php endif;  ?>

            </div>
    </div><!--end response-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
    <div id="response">

                 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                        <div class="container">

                                        <div class="container-grid projects-grid">

                                                <?php
                                                /* Start the Loop */
                                                while ( have_posts() ) :
                                                    the_post();?>

                                                            <div class="grid-item">
                                                                    <a href="<?= the_permalink() ?>">
                                                                        <?php
                                                                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                                                                //the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
  the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); 
                                                                        }?>
                                                                        <h3><?= the_title() ?></h3>
                                                                    </a>
                                                            </div>

                                                <?php endwhile;?>

                             </div><!--end container-grid-->

                         </div><!--end container-fluid-->
                <?php endif;  ?>

                </div>
        </div><!--end response-->
```

a little more about:

```
//Default WordPress
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );     // Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );        // Medium resolution (300 x 300 max height 300px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium_large' );  // Medium Large (added in WP 4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );         // Large resolution (1024 x 1024 max height 1024px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );          // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
```

read the documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: Thank you so much. this worked without the argument :)